# WebCore crashes in OS X application

Tags: objective-c, macos, crash

I've received very similar crash reports from some of my users. I'm not sure about the exact moment of the crash or what may be causing it; what I know is that these crash reports looks very similar.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97c15e1e WebCore::TextIterator::subrange(WebCore::Range*, int, int) + 126
1 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97ce5a93 WebCore::AlternativeTextController::applyAlternativeTextToRange(WebCore::Range const*, WTF::String const&, WebCore::AlternativeTextType, WTF::Vector const&) + 1747
2 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97c07262 WebCore::AlternativeTextController::handleAlternativeTextUIResult(WTF::String const&) + 754
3 com.apple.WebKitLegacy 0x00007fff990da858 -[WebView(WebViewInternal) handleAcceptedAlternativeText:] + 72
4 com.apple.WebKitLegacy 0x00007fff9906e6bd CorrectionPanel::handleAcceptedReplacement(NSString*, NSString*, NSString*, NSCorrectionIndicatorType) + 269
5 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff9d541b8e __120-[NSSpellChecker showCorrectionIndicatorOfType:primaryString:alternativeStrings:forStringInRect:view:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 20
6 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff9d7a1f63 -[NSCorrectionPanel _doDismissAndAccept:] + 198
7 com.apple.Foundation 0x00007fff99190f4e -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 1115
8 com.apple.Foundation 0x00007fff99190a75 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 131
9 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff9d542709 NSSpellCheckerDismissCorrectionsForView + 294
10 com.apple.WebKitLegacy 0x00007fff9902c25c CorrectionPanel::dismiss(WebCore::ReasonForDismissingAlternativeText) + 92
11 com.apple.WebKitLegacy 0x00007fff9903e939 WebAlternativeTextClient::dismissAlternative(WebCore::ReasonForDismissingAlternativeText) + 25
12 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97c1923b WebCore::Editor::textFieldDidEndEditing(WebCore::Element*) + 27
13 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97fa46bf WebCore::FrameLoader::handleUnloadEvents(WebCore::UnloadEventPolicy) + 143
14 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97a5c6db WebCore::FrameLoader::stopLoading(WebCore::UnloadEventPolicy) + 59
15 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97d5765b WebCore::CachedFrame::CachedFrame(WebCore::Frame&) + 155
16 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97d5939e WebCore::CachedPage::CachedPage(WebCore::Page&) + 62
17 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff9853c635 WebCore::PageCache::add(WebCore::HistoryItem&, WebCore::Page&) + 53
18 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff979f5384 WebCore::FrameLoader::commitProvisionalLoad() + 292
19 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97a758ff WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitLoad(char const*, int) + 79
20 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97a75280 WebCore::CachedRawResource::notifyClientsDataWasReceived(char const*, unsigned int) + 160
21 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97d59601 WebCore::CachedRawResource::addDataBuffer(WebCore::SharedBuffer&) + 145
22 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97a74cfa WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didReceiveDataOrBuffer(char const*, int, WTF::PassRefPtr, long long, WebCore::DataPayloadType) + 218
23 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97a93f6c WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didReceiveBuffer(WTF::PassRefPtr, long long, WebCore::DataPayloadType) + 44
24 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff97a93f0c WebCore::ResourceLoader::didReceiveBuffer(WebCore::ResourceHandle*, WTF::PassRefPtr, int) + 44
25 com.apple.WebCore 0x00007fff988f212a -[WebCoreResourceHandleAsDelegate connection:didReceiveDataArray:] + 106
26 com.apple.CFNetwork 0x00007fff9410ab49 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 69
27 com.apple.CFNetwork 0x00007fff9410aa5e -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 233
28 com.apple.CFNetwork 0x00007fff9410a963 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 48
29 com.apple.CFNetwork 0x00007fff9410f652 _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveDataArray(_CFURLConnection*, __CFArray const*, void const*) + 82
30 com.apple.CFNetwork 0x00007fff9410f259 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic29_delegate_didReceiveDataArrayEv_block_invoke + 145
31 com.apple.CFNetwork 0x00007fff942a4519 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 100
32 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff912d340b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
33 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff912e1039 _dispatch_block_invoke + 474
34 com.apple.CFNetwork 0x00007fff9410a820 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 24
35 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff932efd74 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
36 com.apple.CFNetwork 0x00007fff9410a719 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 137
37 com.apple.CFNetwork 0x00007fff9410a5ba MultiplexerSource::perform() + 282
38 com.apple.CFNetwork 0x00007fff9410a3dc MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 72
39 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff9334d881 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
40 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff9332cfbc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
41 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff9332c4df __CFRunLoopRun + 927
42 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff9332bed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
43 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x00007fff88fd1935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
44 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x00007fff88fd176f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
45 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x00007fff88fd15af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
46 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff9ce7aefa _DPSNextEvent + 1067
47 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff9ce7a32a -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
48 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff9ce6ee84 -[NSApplication run] + 682
49 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff9ce3846c NSApplicationMain + 1176
50 libdyld.dylib 0x00007fff9bf3f5ad start + 1
```

Full Crash Log: http://pastebin.com/5upzvMJg

Since it's a EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY I know it means that some object still in use been deallocated, but since I can't reproduce that crash (it only happened with four times in hundreds of users, which probably used the app thousands of times) I can't use NSZombies to find out who is it.

Someone already had that kind of crash? Observations that might help:
- All crashes happened in Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
- The OS X target version of the project is 10.8+

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can consistently reproduce this error on my 10.11.5 Macbook Pro and have seen it on an older Pro (2011) running 10.11.4.  If it helps at all, it appears to be related to submitting a form on a webview while the macOS autocomplete dialog is up on the screen.  So, for example, if I'm on a form and i'm typing some text and the auto-complete dialog comes up and I hit enter, it submits the form and then crashes.

I haven't seen too many people online with this problem outside of some Adobe WebKit bug reports.  Very frustrating problem.

Comment: Just in case anyone ever comes to this one day, my solution to this problem was to call '[webview setContinuousSpellCheckingEnabled:YES]' on the webview.  Yes, that is a 'YES' in that function call.  Counter-intuitively that removes the auto-correct popover that was causing the crash for me.

Comment: Awesome! I was losing my hopes of ever finding a solution. I will test that as soon as possible.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work with me... My users keep getting that crash. What if I use 'NO' instead of 'YES'?

Comment: I believe "NO" is the default

Comment: There is any other possibility? Maybe something you set in the interface builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Go to https://www.youtube.com/channels.
2. Type a misspelled word into the search field *Search channels* (for example, Antz).
3. Wait while the spell checker’s panel with the proposed corrections appears.
4. Press ENTER.

**Result:** App crashes.

**My solution:** Turn off autocorrection.

In the app, choose Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Correct Spelling Automatically or set the value of the key "WebAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled" to NO in the user’s defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"WebAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled"];
```

Comment: It surely reduced the amount of times that I receive that crash. In one week I've only received one crash log with that error in the last version. Maybe that one was caused by the user enabling that option manually and then causing the crash. Maybe the only thing missing to make it perfect is removing the "Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Correct Spelling Automatically" option from the main menu, but still it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue occur in Chrome Canary, disabling spell check was the only fix that worked.